# Assignment Problem for Groups - Convert Brute Force Version to Faster Version

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization, linear-programming, hungarian-algorithm

I am writing an algorithm to assign event participants break-out rooms and prioritizing groupings of people that have not met before.

The cost matrix is 2D matrix where the number is higher if the two participants matched recently.

```js
class Matches {
    constructor(all, group, session) {
        this.all = new Set(all);
        this.group = new Set(group);
        this.session = new Set(session);
    }
}

class User {
    constructor(id, matches) {
        this.id = id;
        this.matches = matches;
    }
}

const user00 = new User(
    0,
    new Matches([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [4], [14])
);
const user01 = new User(1, new Matches([0], [], [13]));
const user02 = new User(2, new Matches([0, 3], [], [12]));
const user03 = new User(3, new Matches([0, 2], [], [11]));
const user04 = new User(4, new Matches([0, 5], [0], [10]));
const user05 = new User(5, new Matches([0, 4], [], [9]));
const user06 = new User(6, new Matches([0, 7], [], [8]));
const user07 = new User(7, new Matches([0, 6], [], [7]));
const user08 = new User(8, new Matches([0, 9], [], [6]));
const user09 = new User(9, new Matches([0, 8], [], [5]));
const user10 = new User(10, new Matches([0, 11], [], [4]));
const user11 = new User(11, new Matches([0, 10], [13], [3]));
const user12 = new User(12, new Matches([0, 13], [], [2]));
const user13 = new User(13, new Matches([12], [11], [1]));
const user14 = new User(14, new Matches([1], [], [0]));
const user15 = new User(14, new Matches([], [], []));

const users = [
    user00,
    user01,
    user02,
    user03,
    user04,
    user05,
    user06,
    user07,
    user08,
    user09,
    user10,
    user11,
    user12,
    user13,
    user14,
    // // user15,
];

const matchCost = 1;
const matchCostGroup = 2;
const matchCostSession = 5;

const costs = Array(users.length)
    .fill()
    .map(() => new Array(users.length).fill(0));

users.forEach((user) => {
    user.matches.all.forEach((match) => {
        if (match >= users.length) return;

        costs[user.id][match] = matchCost;
    });

    user.matches.group.forEach((match) => {
        if (match >= users.length) return;

        costs[user.id][match] += matchCostGroup;
    });

    user.matches.session.forEach((match) => {
        if (match >= users.length) return;

        costs[user.id][match] += matchCostSession;
    });
});

console.log("Costs");
console.table(costs);

const groupCost = (group) => {
    let cost = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < group.length - 1; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < group.length; j++) {
            cost += costs[group[i]][group[j]];
        }
    }
    return cost;
};

const groupsCost = (groups) => {
    return groups.reduce((acc, group) => acc + groupCost(group), 0);
};

const assign = (numGroups, maxGroupSize) => {
    let minCost = Infinity;
    let minGroups;

    let init = Array(numGroups)
        .fill()
        .map(() => new Array(0));

    const stack = [[0, init]];

    while (stack.length > 0) {
        const [userIndex, groups] = stack.pop();

        for (let j = 0; j < groups.length; j++) {
            if (groups[j].length === maxGroupSize) {
                continue;
            }

            if (j > 0 && groups[j - 1].length === 0) {
                break;
            }

            const newGroups = [
                ...groups.slice(0, j),
                [...groups[j], userIndex],
                ...groups.slice(j + 1),
            ];

            if (userIndex === users.length - 1) {
                const thisCost = groupsCost(groups);

                if (thisCost < minCost) {
                    minCost = thisCost;
                    minGroups = newGroups;
                }
            } else {
                stack.push([userIndex + 1, newGroups]);
            }
        }
    }
    return [minCost, minGroups];
};

const numGroups = 5;
const maxGroupSize = 3;

const [minCost, minGroups] = assign(numGroups, maxGroupSize);
console.log(minCost, minGroups);
```

Currently, it takes up to 60 seconds to find an optimum grouping for an event of size 15. Could you please suggest the best algorithm for this problem? I am hoping to get the time down to 3-4s for an event of 100 people.

Thanks!

Comment: if (userIdx < groups.length && i > userIdx) {
 break;
   }
Adding this reduced time to T/numGroups - currently takes 2s for 15 people.

Comment: Are you trying to find the true minimum or a reasonably good fit?  I would think that simply assigning the users one at a time to the group where they incur the lowest cost would already give you a reasonably good minimum.  Clearly it's not perfect.  I don't know if there is a good minimization algorithm algorithm for this (it seems quite possible) but if you don't need the true minimum, this will be much faster than trying all the `groups ^ people` possibilities.

Comment: Also, some sample data would probably help.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I have added some sample data and also added some logic that eliminated duplicated partitions based on Knuth's AOCP.